# ifconfig not updating with new dhcp provided address

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ifconfig

I have a machine that I've setup as a router using Ubuntu 17.10 server.

I have three Ethernet ports: one I use as a WAN [referred here as: ${WAN}], and the other two I've bridged as LAN.

My WAN address is ISP provided via DHCP.

`/etc/network/interface`:

```
auto ${WAN}
iface ${WAN} inet dhcp
```

I have `ddclient` installed, so I've setup a script to test that is working, here is its output [changed slightly for security]:

```
=================================================
WAN IP: via 'ip -4 addr show ${WAN}'
24.163.176.94
174.109.187.251
=================================================
External IP: via 'curl http://icanhazip.com'
174.109.187.251
=================================================
nslookup of mylan.us.to:
174.109.187.251
```

Note the two IPs that are being listed via `ip -4 addr show ${WAN}`. Usually my ISP switches me up randomly between these two IP addresses. At the time of running this script, the correct IP is the 174.109.187.251 address. This led me to check what `ifconfig` showed:

```
${WAN}: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 24.163.176.94  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 24.163.185.255
        ether 90:fb:a6:88:a1:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 823978  bytes 141634338 (141.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93505  bytes 16976560 (16.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

You'll notice that `inet` being shown via `ifconfig` is the **old** IP address.

I've tried restarting networking via:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

I've also rebooted the machine. The `ifconfig` is still giving the wrong IP, and `ip -4 addr show ${WAN}` continues to show both IPs.

Other than these two issues everything else seems to be working fine. NAT is NATing, LAN is forwarding via WAN, `ddclient` is updating with the correct IP address, etc.

I've VERY new to Ubuntu, so I've reached the limit of my debugging skills, so any ideas why this old IP address is sticking around?

EDIT:

```
sudo ifdown ${WAN}
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp1s0/90:fb:a6:88:a1:7a
Sending on   LPF/enp1s0/90:fb:a6:88:a1:7a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE on ${WAN} to 142.254.207.161 port 67 (xid=0x7948571c)
```

Then on:

```
sudo ifup ${WAN}
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/${WAN}/90:fb:a6:88:a1:7a
Sending on   LPF/${WAN}/90:fb:a6:88:a1:7a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x92b2b512)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x92b2b512)
DHCPREQUEST of 174.109.187.251 on ${WAN} to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x12b5b292)
DHCPOFFER of 174.109.187.251 from 69.134.11.87
DHCPACK of 174.109.187.251 from 69.134.11.87
bound to 174.109.187.251 -- renewal in 28592 seconds.
```

Yet, in syslog:

```
5924:Nov 16 17:23:30 router systemd-networkd[528]: enp1s0: DHCPv4 address 24.163.176.94/21 via 24.163.72.1
```

Why the difference?

For the commenter that said /etc/network/interfaces was deprecated:

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ${WAN}:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 server, the use of /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated in favor of netplan. Please edit your question to add the result of the command: `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Comment: It looks correct. Next, I'd comment out all the ethernet settings in /etc/network/interfaces and reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: I'm glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, IFUPDOWN is not pre-installed on Ubuntu 17.10, but at some point during my setup I must have installed it (though I don't remember doing so).

As a result, I had IFUPDOWN making a DHCP client request, AND networkd making a second DHCP client request. IFUPDOWN would receive one IP from my ISP, and networkd would receive another.

Since I'm more familiar with the IFUPDOWN way of configuring networking (as well as every "building a router HOW-TO" using that way), I decided to go strictly with IFUPDOWN.

**BEFORE YOU PROCEED ANY FURTHER WITH REMOVING NETPLAN, CONFIRM YOU HAVE IFUPDOWN INSTALLED:  `sudo apt-get install ifupdown`**

I then disabled netplan via the following steps:

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ${WAN}:
      dhcp4: yes
```

I modified this to:

```
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # For more information, see netplan(5).
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
```

...rebooted and that fixed the issue I was seeing with the two different DHCP provided IP addresses, which confirmed for me that IFUPDOWN was now working correctly as expected.

I checked this in three ways:

- `ip -4 addr show ${WAN} | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'` - see only one DHCP provided address I'm expecting
- `curl http://icanhazip.com` - see the address I'm expecting
- `route` - see the address I'm expecting in the chain.

I then disabled netplan according to the netplan wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan by modified my grub config: `/etc/default/grub`
Changing line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"
```

...executed: `sudo update-grub`, then rebooted the machine.

I then executed:

```
journalctl -p err
Nov 17 11:09:42 router systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Since I don't like to see errors, I issued: `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan` [which is just a symlink to `/lib/netplan/generate`] then rebooted again.

'journalctl -p err', no errors.

```
grep netplan /var/log/syslog
Nov 17 13:12:07 router kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic root=UUID=1e26c91e-0805-44f7-9ae3-3a707fa0d311 ro ipv6.disable=1 netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true
```

...no errors.

So as far as I can tell, netplan is effectively disabled (though in previous versions you could fully uninstall it with apt-get, in 17.10 that is no longer possible).